# Bootstrap flex-grow-0 class fails to achieve it's purpose in my navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar for my webpage which looks currently like this

[Image example of code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3OC5.jpg)

Now the code which I wrote for the same is:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top bg-white">
  <div class="container my-2">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand text-dark font-weight-bold">Rakshit Deshmukh</a>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-info ml-auto">Contact Me</button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNav">
      <span class="fas fa-bars text-dark"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="collapseNav">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link text-dark h6 mx-3">Blogs</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For the div with ID collapseNav, I went to Inspect Element, and even with the class of flex-grow-0 present, the inspect element said that the flex-grow value was 1. Please help me with where I went wrong!

Comment: When I run your code alongside Bootstrap 4 your `flex-grow-0` is honored. Have you eliminated the possibility of conflicting CSS?

Comment: Yes, there was no conflicting CSS - in fact, there was no external CSS at all! Turns out, the CDN I was using was for a previous version of Bootstrap or something. I just changed the CDN and it worked out for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the CDN - I was using a wrong CDN, it seems.

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top bg-white">
      <div class="container my-2">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand text-dark font-weight-bold">Rakshit Deshmukh</a>

        <button class="btn btn-outline-info ml-auto">Contact Me</button>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNav">
          <span class="fas fa-bars text-dark"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="collapseNav">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link text-dark h6 mx-3">Blogs</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```